# Multiset Multisum Problem: Minimum number of elements required to form two subsets, each summing to k or more

Tags: algorithm, subset-sum

I am given an array (better to say, a multiset), say L. Now, I need to tell the minimum number of elements (of L) required to form two subsets (multisets) out of this set such that the sum of the elements of each of the two subsets is at least k (a given integer).

The basic idea which came to my mind was: Initially, we have two empty arrays/ sets. First, add the largest element into one of these. Now, starting with the second largest, I add an element into the subset which has the minimum sum out of the two and go on till I get the sum at least k in both of these. This solution worked in many test cases but later I found a counterexample to this which proved this solution is not correct. The counterexample is:
taking L=[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] and k=16.

I know that this problem is somehow a modified (better to say, Advanced) version of the Subset sum problem, but don't know how to do this. Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that we want to build both subsets from the largest elements of L, so let us assume L is sorted such that it is in decreasing order.

Then the question becomes find smallest n such that L[0:n] can be split into two subsets of value k or more.

This is equivalent to find smallest n such that S=L[0:n] can be split into a single subset of value between k and sum(S)-k (because the other subset will automatically be of value k or more if this is true).

Therefore you can run a standard subset sum algorithm, inserting elements of L in decreasing size, and at each step checking whether there is any solution in the range k to sum(S)-k.

Comment: Did I not understand your solution or you missed my point? Okay, whatever is written is correct, it will give me whether such a **n** exists or not. By modifying the subset sum algorithm, I can also find the number of elements required such the sum is between k amd sum(S)-k, but how do I find the **minimum** number of elements required for the other set to satisfy the given property?

Comment: Oh, actually I did not understand your solution. Now, I got it. Thanks @[Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1139393/peter-de-rivaz).

Comment: So, actually, this solution is okay, but it is not working for large values of n and k. Is there anything better than this?

Comment: How big are your n and k?  This solution should be O(n.k)